# How we can used two different business hours in an Entitlement and Milestones?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I am working on the OOTB `Entitlement Process` and `Milestones`. I have two different business hours Mexico and USA. I want my entitlement to be run for both the business hours, assuming 1 business hour at a time.

How we can used or configure both business hours single entitlement process ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Business hours are applied according to a hierarchy. Salesforce uses the business hours specified at the highest level.
Entitlement management business hours hierarchy

[image]

If you want to use different business hours for different severity levels, **set business hours at the milestone level**. For example, if the severity level of a case increases, the customer may need to be contacted more frequently. You can create a “Last Touch” milestone that changes business hours according to severity level while the other milestones in the entitlement process remain unchanged.

Comment: Can we set Business hours at the Entitlement Process level? Applicable for all the milestone ? Can you show me how we can add business hours at the milestone level ?

Answer (score 0):

BY Traversing through your Entitlement Process you can set your Milestone Level Business Hours.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right, but how can we change the business hours at the run time ? If I change it to some other group owner.

Comment: Then that will check for Time Zone Selected For that owner profile.
Suppose it is INDIAN Time zone of that user profile. Then Entitlement Process Which has lookup to Indian Business Hour will work.
For That you will Have to create Business Hour ex : India Time Zone. And use that in Entitlement Process.

Comment: My questions is can we used two different business hours on a single milestone or an entitlement process based on the group my case is on? Consider OLA scenario and guide